# Visual Studio 2017 - Option Strict will not turn off

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, strict

After a recent update on VS2017. I'm seeing lots of Late binding errors on all projects.

The errors are showing because Option Script of set to on somewhere, but all my projects have the option Option Strict set to Off.

On some projects even if I set Option Strict to Off in the page code behind, I still get the error.

Sometimes if I try to reference Microsoft Visual Basic in the project, the errors go away, sometimes not.

Anyone else experiencing this problem? Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I'm facing same behaviour after updating Visual Studio 2017 to Version 15.5.1 some minutes ago.
Error is given by intellisense, all Projects are built without problems. Alle Projects have set Option Strict to Off. I also get other errors in Intellisense like "Forms is no member of Windows" when using Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No instead of System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No. I think this should have been fixed by MS in one of previous releases?
So it seems like this is a bug in intellisense error detection.
Regards,
Michael

Comment: After repairing VS and disabling all extensions.  This problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be fixed in Rel. 15.5.2!

Answer (score 2):

pLease have a look at
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160609/vb-option-strict-on-warnings-are-shown-on-existing.html
So MS is already aware of the bug and proposes another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. The workaround I found is:
1.  Turn option strict ON
2.  Compile your project (will not succeed due to option strict on)
3.  Turn option strict OFF
4.  Compile your project (compilation success and no more errors)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has now been Fixed in release 15.5.2.

You might have to save a project with Option Strict On then save with Option Strict Off. I didn't have to do that.

Source :https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160609/vb-option-strict-on-warnings-are-shown-on-existing.html